# Human-Mat-Socket grounding question

Tags: esd

I'm looking at ESD mats for soldering. Found one that seems nice. It has two joins to connect wires. The hand wrist band I'm planning to connect to one of the joins has 1M Ohm resistor inside itself. The socket ground plug has 1M Ohm in itself too. The wire connecting the mat to the socket ground plug has 2M Ohm resistor. The path is:

`human <-- 1M Ohm --> mat <-- 2M Ohm --> plug <-- 1M Ohm --> wall socket ground`

Is that connection sequence fine?

Comment: Is it from a reputable supplier known for having a quality record selling such products? If it is there should be a decent brochure or data sheet telling you how to wire it up and what impedances to expect. Maybe you should link those brochures if you don't understand them.

Comment: Why do you need more than 1M from the wrist band to the wall socket ground?

Comment: I have not claimed that I need it. I have asked is the setup right. I have no datasheet, but I think that the question is general, and not relevant to particular product.